# How can I increase the speed of the results in an mysql select statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `SELECT` statement that queries about 115K records.

```
SELECT * 
FROM RC_DATA 
WHERE field_19 = '$county' 
  AND field_178 = 'Active' 
  AND field_1 LIKE '%res%' 
ORDER BY field_176 
LIMIT 8, 4
```

It take around 20 seconds to display the results.

I tried specifying the fields (about 20 of them) instead of using `*` with the same results.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Show us the table's structure and the indexes.

Comment: Yes, field_sysid Unique, BTREE

Comment: Changed to: 
SELECT field_175,field_sysid,field_49,field_165,field_421,field_2306,field_2302,field_46,field_3010,field_2314,field_55,field_2328,field_2346,field_32,field_2294,field_2805,field_9,field_176,field_3187,field_2368,field_2386 
  
FROM $tbl_name USE INDEX (field_sysid) WHERE field_19 = '$county' AND field_178 = 'Active'

and receive error:
mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: Use `mysql_query(...") or die(mysql_error());` to see what error yo uare getting

Comment: Says: Key 'field_sysid' doesn't exist in table 'RC_DATA'

Comment: phpMyAdmin shows field_sysid with the key and index set.

Comment: still gives the error though

Comment: Altered table, added indexes. Much faster now. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Only select the fields you need